# CodeIgniter Base URL Not Applied

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I've been working on my first MVC-Based PHP application recently, using the CodeIgniter Framework. The project is now ready to go live for my friend/user to evaluate. As per the documentation, I have set the base url to 'http://sitename.co.uk/subdir/'.

When I browse to http://sitename.co.uk/subdir I'm redirected to http://sitename.co.uk/sitename/subdir. My shared hosting has a parent directory containing children directories with the name of each site I am hosting. I believe this is perhaps the cause of this.

I have attempted modifying the .htaccess, on the off-chance that this was overwriting the base url defined in config.php, though this did not appear to be the case. The base_url in config.php appears to have no affect on where I'm redirected to when browsing to this page.

The line for the base url currently reads:

$config['base_url'] = 'http://sitename.co.uk/subdir/';

As always, any assistance is appreciated. I have little experience with web publishing.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `$config['base_url']` does not do any redirection check if you have .htaccess it should have this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```